# How to connect 2 external microphones to an Android device

Tags: android, microphone

I'm developing for my End Project a small android application which should be capable of gathering audio directional information.

For that, I am planning to connect the following devices:

-First, one adapter like this one, so I can isolate the microphone line:
http://www.kvconnection.com/product-p/km-droid-2trs.htm

-Then a 2 to 1 jack 3.5 connector:
http://www.aficam.es/images/AUDIO%20SPLITTER%20ADAPTADOR%20A%20DOBLE%20JACK%203,5%20mm.1%20M%20-%202%20H.jpg

-And then 2 mono directional microphones.
The complete schematic should be something like this:
[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/266/sinttuloke.png/]

My questions are:

-Do you see any flaws in what I have just exposed?

-Could I break something if I connect stereo instead of mono microphones into the 2 to 1 connector? Would the design still work?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at this sketch I doubt if it will work as you want (or as I suppose you want). I am pretty sure that you can not for example make one sound louder and the second I do not know maybe lower the frequency. This is because on adapter you will connect those two lanes into one again. The second thing generally is that I am not sure (I`ve never met something like that) if this 2 to 1 thing will work with microphones. In my opinion it is designed to work with two but headphones.

The main reason for that is the way that sound or more specific voltage flaws. In headphones you generate it in device and "duplicate" on headphones. With microphones thing is quite different. It is microphone which "produces" voltage. So in my opinion it will merge the voltage on the output.

But I might be wrong.

Comment: Hi sebap. Thank you for your response. You seem to be making a valid point. Does it mean that the android external microphone input is mono? If so, I am wondering if I could use the mini USB port instead. Something like this: 2 mono microphones + 2 to 1 + jack 3.5 mm to miniUSB adapter ( http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/31u1ohAEsHL._SL500_AA300_.jpg). Thanks for your time! I'll keep researching.

Comment: Well, I`m not sure if it would work anyway. The reason for that, as I said before, is connecting two microphones to one adapter - this is wrong adapter.You can`t get stereo from that. If you really need and want to make stereo input you should make some kind of connector by yourself using some integrated circuit approperiate for that.

Comment: Hi again! Yes, seems that you are right, external microphone input is mono in Android devices (at least it is on my Galaxy S). Now I'm thinking if I could get for android something like this: http://bookmarkblogs.com/_data/userpics/big_thumb/stereo-mic-interface-gives-your-iphone-4-some-better-ears.jpg

Comment: Yes, this is good thing, if you have iPhone. So as i said before you have to make something like this by your own. Why? Because this microphones are connecting to iPhone plug.

Comment: Hi! Yes, those are for Iphone, I haven't found something similar for Android yet. Another thing I am researching now is the possibility of connecting the microphones via bluetooth, but I'm not sure if it can be done easily. I'll keep researching.